# Read File Excel

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, filereader, fast-excel

I read a big file excel with 70,000 rows and 10 columns with JAVA. I use Apache POI to read and get the data but it takes much time like 1 hour. I changed to using fast-excel to read the file but just can read 2,000 row.

Can someone suggest to me how to tunning the Apache poi? Or maybe have other solutions?

Comment: If it's taking an hour to process 70k rows, I highly doubt the bottleneck is the file reader.

Comment: [As per the Apache POI FAQ entry on memory + performance](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10165), 50k rows with 50 columns should take a max of a few seconds on a typical developer machine. Whatever is going wrong must be in your code and not POI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.ttzero:eec:0.5.12` supports reading millions of rows of Excel [github links](https://github.com/wangguanquan/eec), Unfortunately, only Chinese documents are available

```
try (ExcelReader reader = ExcelReader.read(Paths.get("./abc.xlsx"))) {
    // Print
    reader.sheet(0).rows().forEach(System.out::println);

    // Convert to Java Bean
    List<Item> list =  reader.sheet(0)
        .header(1)  // <- Specify the title line number
        .rows()
        .map(row -> row.to(Item.class)) // <- Convert to Java Bean
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As @shmosel mentioned I too feel that your issue is in the file reader. Check if the below code works faster than what you have now.

Try the below code :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ExcelReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("path/to/your/excel/file.xlsx")) {
            
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                // Iterate over cells
                for (Cell cell : row) {
                    
                    System.out.print(cell.toString() + "\t");
                }
                
                System.out.println();
            }

            
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```